# Beans are not Autowired during tests (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

my application normally works fine, but when I run tests, or build application by maven, application is shutting down due tests with errors java.lang.NullPointerException. I debugged it and find out my that my beans in service layer are not Autowired and they are null.
Here is my class with tests:

```
public class CompanyServiceSimpleTest {
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        companyService = new CompanyServiceImpl();
    }

    // Here is sample test
    @Test
    public void testNumberOfCompanies() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, companyService.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

companyService is initialized, but beans in it not. Here is CompanyServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository; // is null

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService; // is null

    @Override
    public List<CompanyDto> findAll() {
        List<CompanyEntity> entities = companyRepository.find(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return entities.stream().map(Translations.COMPANY_DOMAIN_TO_DTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    // ... some other functions
}
```

So when is called companyRepository.find() applications crashes. Here is repository class:

```
@Repository
@Profile("inMemory")
public class CompanyInMemoryRepository implements CompanyRepository {

    private final List<CompanyEntity> DATA = new ArrayList<>();
    private AtomicLong idGenerator = new AtomicLong(3);

    @Override
    public List<CompanyEntity> find(int offset, int limit) {
        return DATA.subList(offset, Math.min(offset+limit, DATA.size()));
    }
    // ... some others functions
}
```

I have set up profile for that service but I had that VM options in Idea:

> -Dspring.profiles.active=develpment,inMemory

So it should works.

Comment: don't try to use the actual beans, use Mocks.

Comment: there's nothing in your test related to spring, so I don't see how @Autowired could work.

Answer (score 1):

To make autowiring work it has to be a Spring integration test. You have to anotate your test class with:

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyApplicationConfig.class})`

If it is a Spring Boot app e.g.:

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApp.class, MyApplicationConfig.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`

More on this topic: http://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring and http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Answer (score 0):

You are not configuring Spring in your TestClasses, so it's impossible to inject anything...
Try configurin your class with 
`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "path to your config xml" })`

A little example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:config/applicationContext.xml"})
public class MyTest {

   @Autowired 
   private MyClass myInjectedClass;

   @Test 
   public void someTest() {
     assertNotNull(myInjectedClass);
   }
}
```